# Meaning of 言われ + ても

Tags: verbs, conjugations, passive-voice

I was looking up the conjugation of `言う`, and the passive form of it is `言われる`. In the sentence below, which I did not write, `ても` gets attached to that verb form after first dropping `る`. Can someone please explain the grammar behind why it was dropped? What does `ても` mean in this case?

> 急にそんなこと**言われても**困るよ。

Comment: The passive form of a verb conjugates further as an 一段 verb. It's that simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
<https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78795/word-by-word-translation-of-%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa%e9%81%85%e3%81%84%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e3%81%ab%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%89%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e5%9b%b0%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99/78814#78814>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

も is roughly "even", "also". Attached to a verb's て-form, it has a meaning of "even (if)".

言われても thus literally means "even if told".

A translation for you sentence might look like this: "I'm going to worry/be in trouble even if you suddenly tell me that!" (even if I'm being told that)

Comment: Personally, I think this is one of the places the "even if" translation doesn't work too well.

Comment: I agree. I did think it was easier to understand the rough idea that way though, hence why I went for some sort of literal translation rather than a proper one. I should have been clearer about that.

Comment: @Thibalator I think the speaker of the sentence is complaining from the '急にそんなこと言われたこと', so your translation doesn't look comfortable to.
I think the correct English translation'd be:
'It's bothering that it's said/told rapidly like that'.

Comment: @Thibalator but your literal translation of 言われても is correct as of what i know.